# org-mode: Adding bibliography

Tags: org-mode

Every time I want to convert an org-file to pdf using org-mode, I need t write the following lines at the end of my file:

`* References:

 \bibliographystyle{plain}

 \bibliography{/path/to/my/bibfile}{}`

In org-mode there is the command `<s TAB` to insert a

```
#begin src 
#end src.
```

Is there something similar for the bibliography? I would like to have these line automatically added to my files, each time
I fire some `<s`-command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers for the price of one:

- Look at the easy templates (section 15.2 of the manual) or
- Use YASnippet therefore (more generic, and usable in all Emacs parts!).

Comment: I used yasnippet for that. Thanks.